# Another unusual java ClassNotFound

Tags: java, linux, sh, raspberry-pi

I have a small programm and several .sh files to execute it. I use Raspberry-pi virtual box emulator to run it. (Don't ask why... just need it.. :) )
So, my .sh file looks like:

```
export HSQLDB_JAR=../lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar

java -classpath $HSQLDB_JAR org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 ../my-hsqldb/my-hsqldb -dbname.0        my-hsqldb
```

I have the needed jars, java is installed properly (checked several times), blah-blah, all the same:

```
rpi@RaspberryPi:/home/snb/my/apps/MyApp/bin$ sh skysql.sh
: not found2: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.Server
```

The most interesting thing, that when I run the script from the sh file directly from bash - it works! But running the .sh file gives this error :(

Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT

The following directories have all of the access rules, so no security issues could happen. They are all accessible.

EDIT #2

I have used the offered answers and comments and that's what happened:

1. Still same stuff :(
2. My .sh file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   export HSQLDB_JAR="$(pwd)/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar"

   echo $HSQLDB_JAR

   java -classpath $HSQLDB_JAR org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 ../my-hsqldb/my-hsqldb -dbname.0 my-hsqldb
   ```

The terminal output is:

```
rpi@RaspberryPi:/home/snb/my/apps/MyApp/bin$ sh skysql.sh
: not found2: 
: not found4: 
/home/snb/my/apps/MyApp/lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar
: not found6: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.Server
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.hsqldb.Server.  Program will exit.
: not found8:
```

So, as you can see, the .jar is actually found and it is in the right path.

Comment: Please show the code that prints `: not found2: `. I'd also like to see the first line of the script.

Comment: I have no idea, why does it print. Could be some issue with the terminal version, though.. It just prints this all of the time, when the. sh file is not executed properly on this VM of mine.

Comment: current working directory issues?

Comment: This seems to be a working directory/path issue...

Comment: I would try `HSQLDB_JAR=\`pwd\`/../lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar` (no need to export)

Comment: Use `HSQLDB_JAR="$PWD/../lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar"` or (if you must call a command) `HSQLDB_JAR=$(pwd)/../lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar`. Avoid backticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a bug in a part of the script that you don't show. Try this:

1. Make sure the first line of your script reads `#!/bin/bash`
2. Make sure you're in the folder that you think you are. Add

   ```
   if [ ! -e "$HSQLDB_JAR" ]; then echo "Jar not found!" ; exit 1 ; fi
   ```

   before calling `java`
3. To see what the shell actually executes, use `-x` (either add `-x` as parameter to the first line or activate it with the command `set -x`).

If you need to generate a path relative to your script, use this code:

```
BASE=$( cd $( dirname "$0" ) > /dev/null && pwd )
HSQLDB_JAR="$BASE/../lib/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar"
```

Always quote variables which contain paths to make sure white space works properly.